# Add Bootstrap popover to a specific div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am trying to add a bootstrap popover to a div element that contains arbitrary content like so (but what I came up with doesn't work):

```
<div id="popover-target">
   <h3>I need a popover</h3>
      <p>
        This is some content for the section
        that needs to be explained by the popover.
      </p>
</div>
<button class="btn">Show popover</button>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.btn').click(function(){
            $('#popover-target').popover({title: 'Title', content: 'Test Content', container: 'body', placement: 'right'});
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I change `$('#popover-target')` to `$('.btn')` then the popover displays correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: is second `$` a typo in `$('$popover-target')`

Comment: @guradio yes it was a typo, sorry fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have just initialized the popover on button click which should work fine, if you hover over the `#popover-target` div after button click. If you want to show it after button click with hovering over it, you can use [`.popover('show')`](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/#popovershow) like:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('#popover-target').popover({
      trigger: 'hover',
      title: 'Title',
      content: 'Test Content',
      placement: 'bottom'
    })
    .popover('show');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function(){
$('.btn').popover({
      container: "body",
      html: true,
      content: function () {
        return '<div class="popover-message">Hello</div>';
      }
    });
    
  
});

$('.btn').click(function(){
      $('#btn').popover();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="popover-target">
   <h3>I need a popover</h3>
      <p>
        This is some content for the section
        that needs to be explained by the popover.
      </p>
</div>
<button class="btn">Show popover</button>
```