# why jquery toggle() does not work in form within a bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-popover

I'm trying to create a small html-form within a dynamic bootstrap popover which works quite good.

But as a fancy version, I'd like to have a hidden `select`-element which only shows up when a checkbox is clicked.

In an earlier version I did this without popovers and used jquerys `toggle()` with an `onclick` event and it worked nicely. But not here.

The following code is what I have so far:

```
var content = '
                <form id="myForm" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="submit_myForm.php">
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="check" class="col-md-10">check this? *</label>
                        <input class="col-md-2" type="checkbox" name="check" value="1" onclick="$(\'#selectToToggle\').toggle();" />
                        <select id="selectToToggle" name="selectToToggle" class="col-md-10 col-md-1" hidden>
                           <option>select something</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
            ';
var title = "Some Title";

$('#myPopover').popover({
            placement : 'right',
            html : true,
            trigger : 'manual', 
            content: content,
            title: title
});
$('#myPopover').popover('show');
```

Is there a reason why the `onclick`-event is not triggered or doesn't work properly? Is there a failure in my code?

I would appreciate any help - thanks :)

EDIT: I think I found the core problem: It seems the id cannot be found within the popover. However, I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `onClick` is in a string, jQuery doesn’t listen for it as it doesn’t know it’s there.

You should give your checkbox an ID, and then listen for the click *after* you’ve added the text to the page.

```
$('#myPopover').popover({
            placement : 'right',
            html : true,
            trigger : 'manual', 
            content: content,
            title: title
});
$('#myCheckbox').on('click', function() {
    $('#selectToToggle').toggle()
});
$('#myPopover').popover('show');
```

Comment: hm... ok I see what you mean. Unfortunately your solution doesn't seem to work. What is somewhat irritating is, that there is no error showing up in the console that the function is not defined or something like that :/

Comment: Put a `console.log('Hullo')` in the `on()` function and see if that’s triggering? Do you have a link to what `popover()` is?

Comment: isn't triggering. I got this construction idea from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456829/add-bootstrap-popover-to-a-specific-div-element. if that is what you mean :)

Comment: I think I found the core problem. It seems that the select-element cannot be found in the popover. Nevertheless, I have no idea how to solve it